# How to define this method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I really stuck with this error and hope someone help me to solve it. 
So, I use this helper:

```
module BooksHelper
  def image_from_amazon(amazon_id)
        image_tag "http://images.amazon.com/images/P/#{amazon_id}.01.ZTZZZZZZ.jpg"
  end
end
```

View file

```
> <%= image_from_amazon(book.amazon_id) %>
```

On my local machine everything working fine except Heroku. Logs:

```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `amazon_id' for #<Book:0x007f06994ea498>):
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320038+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: <% @books.each do |book| %>
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320040+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <div class="book">
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320041+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <div class="cover">
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320042+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= image_from_amazon(book.amazon_id) %>
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320044+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   </div>
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320045+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <div class="content">
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320047+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <h4 class="title"><%= link_to book.title, book %></h4>
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320048+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/books/index.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_books_index_html_erb__843408363563836431_69833158224880'
2015-08-18T16:28:19.320050+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/books/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb__843408363563836431_69833158224880'
```

Comment: Does the books table have an amazon id field? Did you run the migration on heroku.

Comment: Yes I did "heroku run rake db:migrate" but it doesn't help. "heroku run rake db:setup" - help me. So why? Should I create a new database every time after deploy?

Answer (score 2):

This line is the key:

```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `amazon_id' for #<Book:0x007f06994ea498>):
```

Your `book` instance doesn't respond to `amazon_id`. Try checking the value, e.g.

```
puts "amazon_id: #{book.try(:amazon_id)}"
```